# Faz diferença herdar ou não o valor da propriedade "box-sizing"?

Tags: html, css

Eu estou encontrando frequentemente no código e artigos de terceiros, diversas maneiras de definir no CSS como o [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) (***modelo de caixa***) será aplicado aos elementos, porém uma dessas maneiras mais usadas é fazer com que os elementos filhos herdem o valor da propriedade `box-sizing` do elemento pai.

Como, por exemplo:

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
```

No exemplo acima, todos os elementos que estiverem no documento, herdaram o valor `border-box` da propriedade `box-sizing` do elemento `<html>`, mas não necessariamente! Visto que no código poderia existir um elemento pai que tivesse o valor definido como `content-box` e seus filhos herdariam esse valor e não o valor `border-box` do elemento `<html>`.

Nesse caso, existe alguma explicação que justifique o motivo pelo qual usar o snippet de herança acima? Ou o porque dos desenvolvedores preferirem menos, utilizar simplesmente o snippet abaixo (caso não for utilizar `::before` e `::after`) forçando todos os elementos a ter o valor `border-box`:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Da forma que fez no primeiro código o seletor html tem prioridade, então na pratica fica como se fosse só um `* { box-sizing: border-box }`, não faz sentido aplicar aleatoriamente uma propriedade, sendo global ou por descendência, o ideal mesmo e saber como quer que cada elemento se comporte, se quer o comportamento border-box em tudo, então o `*` já resolve, se quer apenas em elementos especifico ou um especifico, delimite isso, não terá nada haver com herança. Recomendo que entenda bem primeiro o uso de border-box: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Observe que a maioria dos frameworks/uikits usam border-box geral/global, porque isso eh intencional deles, nao significa que seja norma. Optei por fechar a pergunta porque o uso do primeiro código esta redundante para o comportamento da pagina, da forma que esta feito, no entanto você ainda pode [edit] a pergunta e tentar melhorar ou elucidar sua necessidade sobre a herança. *Agradeço a compreensão*.

Comment: A conversa ficou extensa e foi [movida para o chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145295/discussion-on-question-by-leandro-faz-diferenca-herdar-ou-nao-o-valor-da-proprie) - Para ler ou acrescentar algo, utilizem o link fornecido.